# Alternative to macros to aid in type safety and reduced repetition

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I am forced to work with a C api that defines a bunch of code very similar to the below

```
// Some old obscure c api

// First bunch of class in namespace ns
struct _ns_A { int a; };
struct _ns_AResponse { int resp; };

// Second bunch of classes in another ns
struct _ns2_B { int b; };
struct _ns2_BResponse { int resp; };

// Lots more classes in more namespaces...

// Bunch of parsing classes in namespace ns
_ns_AResponse* parse_A(_ns_A* a)
{
    // do some work 
    return new _ns_AResponse { a->a * 100 }; 
}

// Parsing class in another ns
_ns2_BResponse* parse_B(_ns2_B* b)
{
    // do some work
    return new _ns2_BResponse { b->b * 100 };
}

// And so on....
```

It creates a parse function named for every single namespace and type instead of using overloaded functions. It also forces the client code to manage memory.

To aid in this I have wrote some code that looks similar to:

```
// EXAMPLE Expansion: std::unique_ptr<_ns_AResponse> parse(_ns_A* a) { auto ret = parse_A(a); return std::unique_ptr<_ns_AResponse>(ret); }
#define REGISTER_INVOKER(NS, TYPE) inline std::unique_ptr<_##NS##_##TYPE##Response> parse(_##NS##_##TYPE* t) \
 { auto ret = parse_##TYPE(t); return std::unique_ptr<_##NS##_##TYPE##Response>(ret); }

// Register a single parse function for each of our types, stipulating namespace and class
REGISTER_INVOKER(ns, A);
REGISTER_INVOKER(ns2, B);
REGISTER_INVOKER(for 1000s of other types)

int main()
{
    // Invoke our parse method with our unique_ptr to _ns_A
    auto a = std::make_unique<_ns_A>();

    auto a_ret = parse(a.get());

    // And so on...
    auto b = std::make_unique<_ns2_B>();

    auto b_ret = parse(b.get());
}
```

The above allows us to have a single parse call that not only manages memory usage for us but is overloaded by type to allow us to use it in a much more c++ oriented way.

The question I have is the following:

Is there a more suitable way to do this without having to resort to using macros? I have full use of C++17 as well as boost. I would rather not have to pollute our codebase with macros unless I am forced to.

Comment: imho the question would be nicer if you add one example of the macro expansion, i am still trying to decipher it

Comment: Sure. Two seconds

Comment: I see no way of achieving desired functionality without macros.

Comment: @user463035818 it just creates a function from arguments using `##`-concatenation.

Comment: You could at least make it much shorter if you have the same namespace or type lots of times. Just create a short-lived macro passing that and one argument on.

Comment: Is `parse_a` part of that C API? Because `new` is C++ and otherwise `delete`ing a `malloc`'d object is UB.

Comment: @Asu - Yes this example is contrived. I have a custom deleter on my unique_ptr in the real code that invokes the correct malloc/free functions

Comment: How did they manage to get C code into a namespace? Anyway I'd write a tool to generate C++ wrappers for this code automatically.

Comment: @n.m. They just append the type with the namespace i.e. _ns_A or _ns1_B etc. Any pointers on how to write the tool to generate it?

Comment: I'd probably use libclang and capture all function names that match an interesting pattern and output wrappers for those.

Answer (score 4):

Got it! It seems to work.

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

template<auto Parser>
inline auto invoker = [](auto* ptr, decltype(Parser(ptr)) = {})
{
    return std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(Parser(ptr))>>{Parser(ptr)};
};

constexpr auto parse = overloaded {
    invoker<parse_A>,
    invoker<parse_B>
};

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<_ns_A>();
    auto a_ret = parse(a.get());
    std::cout << a_ret->resp << '\n';

    auto b = std::make_unique<_ns2_B>();
    auto b_ret = parse(b.get());
    std::cout << b_ret->resp << '\n';
}
```

You only have to specify the parser function for each of those.

I picked up `overloaded` from somewhere I don't recall, and is usually used for vistor patterns.

The second parameter is a dummy to resolve ambiguity introduced by `auto* ptr` by forcing the lambda function to only be valid when `ptr` can be passed to `Parser`.

I only hope you're not going to try to compile this on MSVC.

Comment: you took `overload` probably from [std::visit documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh right. I know it's there too but IIRC I first got it from Jason Turner's videos.

Comment: Regular functor might allow to have "cleaner" `operator ()`.

Comment: [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j7DGIBzsEolzVL08)'s a slight modification to cut down even more on `parse`'s declaration syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

> I would rather not have to pollute our codebase with macros unless I am forced to.

You can avoid spreading the usage of macors all over your code by making `parse` a template and use a trait:

```
tempalte <typename T>
struct parse_trait;

template <typename T> 
std::unique_ptr<typename parse_trait<T>::response> 
parse( typename parse_trait<T>::type* a) {
    return parse_trait<T>::do_parse(a);
}
```

And then provide a specialization for each type

```
template <>
struct parse_trait<_ns_A> {
    using type = _ns_A;
    using response = _ns_AResponse;
    static std::unique_ptr<response> do_parse(type* a) { return parse_A(a); }
};
```

There might be typos (not tested) but I hope you get the idea.

Not really sure if it is worth the effort, but now you can make this last part in a macro (just replace your `REGISTER(NS,TYPE)` with a macro that specializes the trait). The user will not notice that there is a macro involved when calling `parse`.

Comment: Did consider this but there are 10000 odd types. This would be some serious typing :)

Comment: @JamesMoore as I wrote in the last part: Make the specialization of the trait via a macro.

Comment: @JamesMoore only the macro definition will be 2-3 lines more. For each type you can still write `REGISTER_INVOKER(ns, A);` (to specialize the trait)

Comment: Yes my bad, Investigating this now